# How to redirect a link with utm parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the link `mydomain.com/?utm_source=xxx&lang=de` and I would like to redirect this to
`mydomain.com/de/?utm_source=xxx`. I would like to do the same redirection for all the languages except `en` which redirects to `mydomain.com/?utm_source=xxx`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(de|ar)
# exclude all requests starting with /wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1? [L,R=302]
```

The above code redirects but is not include the utm_source parameter. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Any advice?”_ - yes, of course: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```sh
# exclude all requests starting with /wp-admin/

# lang=en
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?lang=en&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp-admin/ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

# lang other than en
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?lang=([a-z]{2})&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp-admin/ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3 [R=302,NE,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Hello @anubhava. Thanks for your answer. When the lang=en it's work. However when lang=something different is not work. For example when the lang=de then redirect you to mydomain.com/utm_source=xxx&/?utm_source=xxx